# project tango device outdated

Tags: android-studio, google-project-tango

Project Tango prompts me "Tango device outdated"when I run tango-examples-java.And I have already upgrade my tango system to latest version.What's wrong with my tango?how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark:
Have you recompiled tango-examples-java since the latest release?  There are breaking changes in [Eisa](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes), and so there is a new release of the [tango-examples-java](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/commit/2dc4c02e99ff443d07278c7dbeb7acabbf2e4e29) which need pulling down from git and deploying to your tango.
You'd expect it to say "Tango Device Incompatible" or something, but I know this has caused several others issues so thought i'd mention it anyway.